# Determine if reserved item is available when extending the reservation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I am having trouble with a scenario where a user edits their `reservation` in my `tool` borrowing application. Specifically when the `user` wants the same tool but needs to pick it up hours/days before and/or return it hours/days later than their current `reservation`.

For instance, the user has

```
{ 
  tool: "impact wrench", 
  pickup_at: 05-06-2023 8:00 AM, 
  return_at: 05-07-2023 6:00 PM 
}
```

but wants

```
{
  tool: "impact wrench", 
  pickup_at: 05-05-2023 8:00 AM, 
  return_at: 05-08-2023 2:00 PM 
}
```

One way to determine if the tool is available could be to check if the impact wrench is available from the `new pickup_at` to the `old pickup_at` and then check if it's available from the `old return_at` to the `new return_at`?

```
a = Reservation.where("tool_id = ? and pickup_at <= ? and return_at >= 2", 
       t_id, new_pickup_at, current_pickup_at).any?

b = Reservation.where("tool_id = ? and pickup_at <= ? and return_at >= 2", 
       t_id, current_return_at, new_return_at).any?

tool_available = a & b
```

Is there a {better | preferred | more efficient} way?

Comment: What database are you using? On Postgres you can use `(pickup_at, return_at) OVERLAPS (new_pickup_at, new_return_at)` to find other reservations that would overlap.

Comment: It's also very unclear from looking at this code why `Tool.reservations` doesn't cause a NoMethod error. This should be an instance method. Have you declared some kind of wacky scope or resassigned the constant or is this just a typo in the question?

Comment: Its Postgres. Yes. Tool.reservations would cause an error. It should just be Reservation

Comment: Which would cause the exact same error.

Comment: Replacing Tool.reservations.where with Reservation.where is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the instance or the ID of the current reservation, you can execute only one query by excluding that reservation in your SQL sentence. Something like:

```
reserved = Reservation.where("tool_id = ? AND pickup_at <= ? AND return_at >= ? AND id != ?", 
       tool_id, new_return_at, new_pickup_at, current_reservation.id).any?

tool_available = !reserved
```

Comment: This would work as needed if new_pickup_at and new_return_at were switched. 
`reserved = Reservation.where(... tool_id, new_return_at, new_pickup_at, ...).any?`

Answer (score 0):

To find if there are colliding reservations use the OVERLAPS operator:

```
Reservation.where.not(id: current_reservation.id)
           .where(
             "(pickup_at, return_at) OVERLAPS (pickup_at, ?)", new_return_at 
           )
           .exists?
```